# How to traverse nodes to capture text for use in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to capture the value of the product description when an image link is clicked. Then use that product description in a Google Tag Manager variable. Here's a sample of the relevant page source:

```
<div class="item2">
    <div class="list-image">
        <a href="https://example.com/product1">
            <img alt="" src="https://example.com/product-thumbnail.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="list-desc">
        <h3>
            <a href="https://example.com/product1">PRODUCT DESCRIPTION</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The user can click either the div class=item2 or div class=list image to trigger the link click.

I'm thinking the answer will involve using .closest() and/or a combination of parentElement, nextElementSibling but I cannot get it to work in Google Tag Manager.

I've tried various combinations using the GTM Datalayer-type Variable and the Custom Javascript-type variable without success.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you need to learn how loops work.

Comment: @PHPglue I don't believe this is an issue of loops. The image and product description are always paired in this manner and I only need to grab the description of the product which was clicked.

Comment: If you have any control over the markup it would be much better to add a title attribute with the description to the links, to a "just links" trigger and read the title from the {{Click Element}} (or you might use a data attribute).

Comment: @EikePierstorff - Amen. I wish I could but no such luck. Thx though